# Changing date format in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing a date; the format of the original string is `YYYY/DD/MM HH:MM:SS`.
I am trying to convert the string into a datetime format, by using

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], errors='coerce')
```

but plotting it I can see it doesn't recognize the correct format.
Can you help me to understand whether there is an option to give python the correct format to read the column?
I have seen the `format` tag for `to_datetime` function, but I can't use it correctly.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: can you post the output of `print(df.dtypes)` __after __  the call of `pd.to_datetime(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format='%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a non-standard date format. It should be YYYY-MM-DD. Try formating with the strptime() method.

```
time.strptime('2016/15/07', '%Y/%d/%m')
```

If you need to get it to a string after that use time.strftime().

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can I also deal with time with this method?